# Unable to get #pragma multi_compile working for this shader property

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, pragma, preprocessor-directive

I have the following shader which works as expected, wanted to add a dropdown enumeration to be able to show only vertex colors for debugging but it just doesn't want to work.

```
Shader "Unlit Vertex Color"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Cutoff ("Alpha cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Brightness("Brightness", Range(0.0, 10.0)) = 1
        _Gamma("Gamma", Range(0.0, 10.0)) = 1

        [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap("Pixel snap", Float) = 0
        [MaterialToggle] VertexColor("Vertex color", Float) = 1
        [MaterialEnum(Off, 0, Front, 1, Back, 2)] Culling("Culling", Int) = 2
        // BUG does not work
        [KeywordEnum(Default, Colors)] RenderMode("Render mode", Float) = 0
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "Queue"="AlphaTest"
            "IgnoreProjector"="True"
            "RenderType"="TransparentCutout"
        }

        LOD 100
        Lighting Off
        Cull[Culling]

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile _ PIXELSNAP_ON
            #pragma multi_compile _ VERTEXCOLOR_ON
            #pragma multi_compile   RENDERMODE_DEFAULT_ON RENDERMODE_COLORS_ON

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 color : COLOR;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 color : COLOR;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            fixed _Cutoff;
            fixed _Brightness;
            fixed _Gamma;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                o.color = v.color;
                o.color.w = 1.0;

#ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
                o.vertex = UnityPixelSnap(o.vertex);
#endif
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                clip(col.a - _Cutoff);

#ifdef VERTEXCOLOR_ON
                col *= i.color;
#endif

                // BUG show one or the other, always falls back to #1
#ifdef RENDERMODE_DEFAULT_ON
                col = float4(1,1,1,1);
#elif RENDERMODE_COLORS_ON
                col = float4(0,0,0,0);
#endif

                col.rgb *= _Brightness;
                col.rgb = pow(col.rgb, 1.0 / _Gamma);

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

When I ask Unity to show the variants that were compiled, indeed they're correct:

i.e. I want either `RENDERMODE_DEFAULT_ON` or `RENDERMODE_COLORS_ON` to be active at any time then do the appropriate rendering.

```
// Total snippets: 1
// -----------------------------------------
// Snippet #0 platforms ffffffff:
Keywords always included into build: PIXELSNAP_ON RENDERMODE_COLORS_ON RENDERMODE_DEFAULT_ON VERTEXCOLOR_ON

8 keyword variants used in scene:

RENDERMODE_DEFAULT_ON
RENDERMODE_COLORS_ON
RENDERMODE_DEFAULT_ON VERTEXCOLOR_ON
RENDERMODE_COLORS_ON VERTEXCOLOR_ON
PIXELSNAP_ON RENDERMODE_DEFAULT_ON
PIXELSNAP_ON RENDERMODE_COLORS_ON
PIXELSNAP_ON RENDERMODE_DEFAULT_ON VERTEXCOLOR_ON
PIXELSNAP_ON RENDERMODE_COLORS_ON VERTEXCOLOR_ON
```

I've been looking at the only official [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyDrawer.html) there is as well as grep-ing through the [builtin shaders](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) to find more examples to look at, `RENDERMODE_DEFAULT_ON` is always set even though I set render mode to `RENDERMODE_COLORS_ON` in the shader inspector.

**Question:**

How is a `KeywordEnum` supposed to be implemented and used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer:

Remove `_ON` suffixes on these definitions and it'll work.